# Axios request failing on signed version of cordova app

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, cordova, axios

I am developing a Cordova application with Axios and React. I can build this app with Cordova and run the resulting APK on my phone with no problems whatsoever. However, when I sign and zipalign the app and put it on the Play store - network requests do not work.

This is an example of a request :

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://darajava.ie:8888/api/api",
  headers: {
    'accept': 'application/json' 
  }
});

instance.post('authenticate', querystring.stringify({
    username,
    password,
})).then((res) => {
  console.log('LOG ' + JSON.stringify(res));
}).catch(function (error) {
  console.log('ERR ' + JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

The response on the unsigned apk (on the actual phone) is normal, whereas we get "`Network Error`" from the Play store version. I did some research on Axios' `Network Error` and it seems that that occurs when it cannot reach the server. Keep in mind that all other requests fail too.

Does anybody know where I would even start to debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the newer versions of Android do not support cleartext traffic. Either explicitly allow cleartext or use a secure server.